# Error adding user profile

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the SoftLayer REST API to add a user profile using URL https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer.json and a post method.

The parameters passed are:

```
{
     "parameters" :
 [
   { "address1" : "2544 Nice Road",
     "city" : "Atlantic City",
           "companyName" : "Cognitive Research",
     "state" : "NJ",
           "country" : "US",
     "postalCode" :  "00000",
         "firstName" : "Fexxx",
         "lastName" : "Hexxx",
         "email" : "niceguy@us.crazy.net",
     "permissionSystemVersion" : "1",
     "timezoneId" : "117",
     "username" : "cu-thxxxx@us.ibm.com",
     "secondaryPasswordTimeoutDays" : 90,
     "userStatusId" : 1001
    },
           "xx0nn1mm!",
           "xx0nn1mm!"
  ]
  }
```

The error is RC 500 msg is "Internal Server Error" content is "error":"The property \'firstName\' must be set to create an instance of \'SoftLayer_User_Customer\'.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_MissingCreationProperty"

This has worked in the past, but today it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The following error is displayed when using your configuration: `"error": "Invalid password`.

I changed the `password` that meets these requirements:

```
Password must:
   contain at least 1 upper character
   contain at least 1 lower character
   contain at least 1 special character
   be at least 8 characters long
```

I was able to create a new `use customer` using the following:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/createObject.json

Method: POST

Json Payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "address1": "2544 Nice Road",
      "city": "Atlantic City",
      "companyName": "Cognitive Research",
      "state": "NJ",
      "country": "US",
      "postalCode": "00000",
      "firstName": "Fexxx",
      "lastName": "Hexxx",
      "email": "niceguy@us.crazy.net",
      "permissionSystemVersion": "1",
      "timezoneId": "117",
      "username": "cu-thxxxx@us.ibm.com",
      "secondaryPasswordTimeoutDays": 90,
      "userStatusId": 1001
    },
    "Xx0nn1mm!",
    "Xx0nn1mm!"
  ]
}
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Is there anyway I can send you the actual parameter data I am specifiying. The password I am specifying does actually meet the password requirement. As this is a public forum I did not want to specify the actual data. Can I open a SofLayer ticket and supply the real data?

Comment: Please open a SoftLayer ticket in order to isolate the using the actual data.

Comment: Last night I experimented and the changed the statement '"username": "cu-thxxxx@us.ibm.com"', to '"username": "test-thxxxx@us.ibm.com",' and it worked. so I tried to add the profile using the statement '"username": "cu-thxxxx@us.ibm.com",' and it failed.              I ran the script this morning using te statemet '"username": "cu-thxxxx@us.ibm.com",' and it worked.  I am at a loss for what the problem really was..

Comment: I misspoke,  It didn't work this morning.  Writing a SoftLayer ticket

Comment: I misspoke.  I tried again this morning and it failed.  Writing a SoftLayer ticket.